# Can't import Landsat 3 to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I'm trying to add Landsat 3 imagery in Google Earth Engine but no image is being displayed in the map, it shows null value.
The code sample is the following:

```js
var L3 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LM03/C02/T1")
var image = L3.filterBounds(ROI)
               .filterDate ('1980-09-01','1981-08-31')
               .filterBounds(ROI)
               .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
              .first()
print (image)
```

Results: image(0bands)

Comment: Please provide significant details on how you're importing the data etc.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. AS a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site, but to do that, we need to know as much information about your procedure as possible. Single-sentence Questions are unlikely to contain enough details for resolution. Please [Edit] your Question to explain your procedure.

Comment: Probably there aren't any images in your ROI over your specified date range. We can't check because you didn't make your ROI available. But I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes probably this. I want to elaborate Land Use Land Cover for the year 1980 with Google Earth Engine, what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Before 2000, there are many areas with large coverage gaps.

Compare with [USGS Earth Explorer as described here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help_missing_images#landsat). If USGS doesn't have an image for that ROI, EE doesn't either.